# Trouble converting Javascript array into JQuery for IE7 compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to convert a line in Javascript so that the functionality works in IE7. Below is the code I am trying to convert.  Obviously IE doesn't like the class attribute being set which is where the issue occurs.  So my solution was to translate it using JQuery for browser compatibility.  But I am having trouble converting the array into something JQuery understands.

This is the code:

```
    ulAccNm.children[iVal].setAttribute("class", "show");
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
  $(ulAccNm).children(jQuery.inArray("iVal")).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
```

The variable of iVal translates into the total number of children to the parent and loops through each to determine to add a class or not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `ulAccNm`? where is this "loop" you describe?

Comment: What was the purpose of `.children(jQuery.inArray("iVal"))`? all you needed there was `.children().eq(ival)`

Comment: I forgot about that Kevin B.  That corrected the problem nicely.  If you create an answer I would be happy to accept it as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing by using Kevin B's suggestion of .children().eq(ival) and this makes it work

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a lot here, but I think this will translate:

```
$($(ulAccNm).children()[iVal]).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
```

However, if you want to do this to ALL the children, you don't need an explicit loop with `iVal`. Just use

```
$(ulAccNm).children().addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to try changing your loop structure from a for loop to the jQuery.each method:

```
$(ulAccNm).children().each(function () {
    // Decide if the class needs to be changed
    if (needsToBeChanged)
        $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
})
```

Comment: Ended up fixing by using Kevin B's suggestion of .children().eq(ival) and this makes it work.